# How to implement a balance system on a car going on two wheels

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Hey guys i'am developing a new race game , so I was wondering if there are any scripts that would allow the car to run on two wheels, what I want to do is implement weight shifting when the car turns left or right.

I'm currently working on a code that makes the car move rotate and break , but as I said I want to apply a balance system on wheels.

```
if (wheel.transform.localPosition.z > 0)
    wheel.steerAngle = angle;

if (wheel.transform.localPosition.z < 0)
{
    wheel.brakeTorque = handBrake;
}

if (wheel.transform.localPosition.z < 0 && driveType != DriveType.FrontWheelDrive)
{
    wheel.motorTorque = torque;
}

if (wheel.transform.localPosition.z >= 0 && driveType != DriveType.RearWheelDrive)
{
    wheel.motorTorque = torque;
}
```

Comment: You should look for a segway-type vehicle. So that the balancing works. Have you tried to do with a rigidbody?

Comment: Like a bike then?

Comment: Make special colliders that hold the car up in the physics sim. You don't ***care*** if the physics is accurate (it never will be), it just needs to *look* like it for the player. Balancing a car on two wheels is difficult in real life, getting it to happen in a physics simulation is neigh on impossible (so don't bother, just fake it).